# .capitalize() doesn't work in Python in this case

Tags: python, string, capitalize

Given a list of words (text), i want to take each word except the first one and capitalize it. It doesn't work for neither i.capitalize() and i = i.capitalize(). Why?

```
def capitalize_words(text):
    for i in text[1:]:
        i.capitalize()
    return text
```

Comment: Because you return the original list that has not been changed

Comment: The function receives the variable text. 
Then it runs a for loop, but within that loop the variable text remains unchanged. 
You then return the variable text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you return the original list without mutate its values. The line `i.capitalize()` has no affect on the output of your function.

Instead, you can populate a new list and return it, for example:

```
def capitalize_words(text):
    capit_text = []
    for i in text[1:]:
        capit_text.append(i.capitalize())
    return capit_text
```

or, using list comprehension:

```
def capitalize_words(text):
    return [i.capitalize() for i in text[1:]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why the elements of the text are not capitalised when it works well with individual strings.

Comment: They are not capitalized in your code because you don't mutate the original `text` list. The line `i.capitalize()` inside your loop has no affect on the output of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use should return the modified data:

```
def capitalize_words(text):
    return " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in text])
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask to join the returned list of words.

Comment: This returns only text[1:], I need text[0] as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because you return the original list that has not been changed

```
def capitalize_words(text):
    return [word.capitalize() for word in text[1:]]
```

and if you want also `text[0]` but not capitalized

```
return [text[0]] + [word.capitalize() for word in text[1:]]
```

Comment: But why it has not been changed? If I use .capitalize() on a string, it changes the string.

Comment: You iterate over your list, capitalize the word and then throw it away.

Comment: yep agreed @buran, will delete the comment